# Catch Error JSON Parse Error: Unrecognized token'<' - react-native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I have a react native app which has being working well on many devises, by recently I am getting "Catch Error JSON Parse Error: Unrecognised token'<'" on some devises, both Android and IOS.

See Code

```
fetch(url, {method: 'POST', headers: {Authorization : `Bearer ${user.token}`}})
            .then(response => {
                const statusCode = response.status;
                const responseJson = response.json();
                return Promise.all([statusCode, responseJson]);
            })
            .then(res => {
                const statusCode = res[0];
                const responseJson = res[1];
                // console.log(responseJson);
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    if (responseJson.reload.status != 1 ) {
                        Alert.alert(I18n.t('phrases.transaction_failed'), I18n.t('phrases.transaction_not_completed') + ' - ' + responseJson.transaction.status_desc)
                    }else{
                        Actions.success({data: responseJson});
                    }
                }else if(statusCode == 422){
                    alert('missing fields');
                    console.warn(responseJson);
                }else{
                    Alert.alert(I18n.t('words.error'), responseJson.message);
                    console.log(res);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                alert('Catch Error ' + err.message);
                console.log(err);
            }).finally( fin => this.setState({ loading: false }) )
    }
```

Comment: I'll suggest that you use some sort of tracing in your app like sentry or some other tool to capture the logs, it will be easier for you track and trace bugs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Please include more details regarding the issue. The question is very generic and very unlikely to get answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that in some situations, the endpoint you're calling isn't returning JSON, it's returning HTML, probably an error page accompanying an HTTP error. So you'll need to check for that in your app and diagnose why it's happening in some situations and not in others.

So why are you trying to parse HTML as JSON? You haven't shown us any code, but my guess is that you've run into the footgun in the `fetch` API and have code like this:

```
fetch("/your/endpoint")
.then(response => response.json()) // <=== This is the footgun
.then(data => {
    // ...use the data...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...report the error...
});
```

The problem is that `fetch` doesn't reject the promise on HTTP errors, only network errors. You need to check that you didn't get an HTTP 500, 404, etc. status code:

```
fetch("/your/endpoint")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...use the data...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...report the error...
});
```